# Irrational feature ID behavior in PyQGIS script

Tags: pyqgis

I've written a script to determine the coordinates of a point shapefile and insert them into its attribute table.

It works perfectly when the ID sequence of the indiviual features begins with 0, yet when the scheme begins with a number other than 0 the coordinate pairs are returned as null.

I can't trace the problem in the script because I when I enter the commands interactively in the console, it works perfectly.

Here is the code as it appears in the script:

```
import PyQt4

cLayer = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().currentLayer()
LenFields = len(cLayer.pendingFields()) # to determine where x,y will go in the table
provider = cLayer.dataProvider()
caps = provider.capabilities()

names = ["Longitude", "Latitude"]
    for i in names:
        ind = provider.fieldNameIndex(i)
        try:
             if ind == -1:
                if caps & QgsVectorDataProvider.AddAttributes:
                    res = provider.addAttributes([QgsField(i, PyQt4.QtCore.QVariant.Double)])
        except:
            print False

cLayer.commitChanges() # Need to create the Attributes before they can be populated

cLayer.startEditing()
for f in cLayer.getFeatures():
    cLayer.changeAttributeValue(f["ID"], LenFields, f.geometry().asPoint()[0]) #Longitude
    cLayer.changeAttributeValue(f["ID"] , LenFields+1, f.geometry().asPoint()[1]) #Latitude

cLayer.commitChanges()
```

Can anyone see where the problem comes from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value retrieved by `f["ID"]` does not necessarily match the feature id used internally on which changeAttributeValue depends.

Change your update statement to use the feature id instead of your data's id:

```
for f in cLayer.getFeatures():
    cLayer.changeAttributeValue(f.id(), LenFields, f.geometry().asPoint()[0]) #Longitude
    cLayer.changeAttributeValue(f.id() , LenFields+1, f.geometry().asPoint()[1]) #Latitude
```